# How does allocating more memory to Minecraft prevent stuttering?

Tags: garbage-collection, jvm, minecraft

When playing Minecraft with a heavyweight mod pack without increasing the memory allocation you can sometimes see a lot of stuttering: it runs smoothly for about a second then pauses for about a second. I assumed that this was due to GC with some part of the code creating a lot of temporary objects in the main loop.

Allocating more memory before launching the game cures it. My question is, what's going on under the hood that means extra memory can prevent the stuttering rather than just increasing its period?

Comment: The costs of garbage collection scale with the amount of *live* objects. More memory means, more time between gc cycles, means more chances for objects to die, means less work for the gc.

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail?  Specifically, what JDK are you using (I assume 8) and what are the command line flags you start with? Knowing that it will be easier to give an answer to the question.